# KeyError returned during filtering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter two columns. I am looking for rows from `Col1` or `Col2` that contain the words `"car washing"` and `"train"`.

I have tried as follows:

```
filtered=df[df['Col1','Col2'].str.lower().str.contains('car washing','train')]
```

However, I have got the following error:

```
  2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
...

KeyError: ('Col1', 'Col2')
```

Could you please tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: to access a list of columns, one should use double bracket: `df[['Col1','Col2']]`.

Comment: Thank you @QuangHoang. I missed it

Comment: However, after editing it, I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @still_learning is your condition **both** 'car washing' and 'train' or does **either** match work?. You could do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390726/matching-keywords-strings-with-a-pandas-dataframe/61390910#61390910, though with a DataFrame we'll need to apply it column wise, not too different.

Comment: Hi @ALollz. It is for  both 'car washing' and 'train'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with this:

```
filtered=df[df[['Col1','Col2']].sum(axis=1).str.contains('car washing|train', case=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The KeyError here is most probably referring that the columns with names 'Col1' and 'Col2' does not exist. You can use sep = '\s*,\s*' to take care of spaces in column names when importing the dataset. refer to this: [Key error when selecting columns in pandas dataframe after read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv)