# Checking if any word in a string appears in a list using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, any

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column of several thousands of comments. I would like to iterate through every row in the column, check to see if the comment contains any word found in a list of words I've created, and if the comment contains a word from my list I want to label it as such in a separate column. This is what I have so far in my code:

```
retirement_words_list = ['match','matching','401k','retirement','retire','rsu','rrsp']

def word_checker(row):
    for sentence in df['comments']: 
        if any(word in re.findall(r'\w+', sentence.lower()) for word in retirement_words_list):
            return '401k/Retirement'
        else:
            return 'Other'

df['topic'] = df.apply(word_checker,axis=1)
```

The code is labeling every single comment in my dataframe as 'Other' even though I have double-checked that many comments contain one or several of the words from my list. Any ideas for how I may correct my code? I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Something like the first option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390726/matching-keywords-strings-with-a-pandas-dataframe/61390910#61390910? Just also specify `case=False` as an argument for `str.contains`

Comment: Changing `retirement_words_list` to a set might make the lookup faster.  Testing for membership in a list is O(n), while testing for membership in a set is O(1) -- details here:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @jsmart That depends how it is being used. Currently the code is not using `retirement_words_list` for inclusion testing, only for iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably more convenient to have a set version of `retirements_word_list` (for efficient inclusing testing) and then loop over words in the sentence, checking inclusion in this set, rather than the other way round:

```
retirement_words_list = ['match','matching','401k','retirement','retire','rsu','rrsp']

retirement_words_set = set(retirement_words_list)
```

and then

```
    if any(word in retirement_words_list for word in sentence.lower().split()):
            # .... etc ....
```

Your code is just checking whether any word in `retirement_words_list` is a substring of the sentence, but in fact you must be looking for whole-word matches or it wouldn't make sense to include `'matching'` and `'retirement'` on the list given that `'match'` and `'retire'` are already included. Hence the use of `split` -- and the reason why we can then also reverse the logic.

**NOTE**: You may need some further changes because your function `word_checker` has a parameter called `row` which it does not use.  Possibly what you meant to do was something like:

```
def word_checker(sentence):
    if any(word in retirement_words_list for word in sentence.lower().split()):
        return '401k/Retirement'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

and:

```
df['topic'] = df['comments'].apply(word_checker,axis=1)
```

where `sentence` is the contents of each row from the `comments` column.

Comment: Thank you very much Alani. Guess my approach was slightly backwards and not fully fleshed out. I spent quite a while trying to troubleshoot this on my own before posting. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this simplified version (without regex) work?

```
if any(word in sentence.lower() for word in retirement_words_list):
```

Comment: Hi Rafael. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, using the simplified version you suggested using yield the same results. I've also tried doing sentence.lower.split() and got the same results.

Comment: Interesting, I have tried with some dump sentence and it worked. Perhaps your sentence is of a different form? Can you check what `sentence` is, is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: That's a very good point. I checked to make sure that values in that column are in string format as I expected. Actually, I tried following the method used in the link that ALloz included and this seems to have done the trick.  Thank you very much Rafael, for taking the time to answer!