# How to test if a df['column'] contains one of the substrings in a list, in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pd dataframe that has a column that contains values as ['cat, pet','dog, pet','dog','bird', 'bird, pet','tail', 'cat, tail'], and I want to find all places where s contains both of ['cat', 'pet'], and extract the rows that match.

NOTICE that this question is not made for the specific case  ['cat', 'pet'], but for a dynamic input that could handle any combination of lists, and the dataframe is more than 10.000 rows long.

My goal is to filter the rows based on values contained in a specific column

I know that if I want to find 'cat' OR 'pet', I just filter like:

```
 search = ['cat', 'pet']
 df[df['column'].str.contains('|'.join(search))]
```

But what if I want to match 'cat' AND 'pet' or other lists with different combinations of values??

I tried:

```
df[df['column'].str.contains('&'.join(search))]
But it is not working for me :/
```

Also tried:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([df['column'].str.contains(word) for word in search])
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011734/pandas-dataframe-str-contains-and-operation

Comment: The reason the OR works is because | is a regex term. There is no direct equivalent for AND. See Chris's linked post for how

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390726/matching-keywords-strings-with-a-pandas-dataframe/61390910#61390910

Comment: Thank you @ALollz, I tried np.logical_and.reduce([dfd['column'].str.contains(word) for word in search]) but is still not working, what I am doing wrong

Comment: @TheDan is it possible the values in your column are lists, or a list of lists and not strings?

Comment: the values appear to be object whr I use df.dtypes 
But the error that appears isNameError: name 'df' is not defined, and it actually is defined, I can see the df when debugging, it really does exist and I can use it with other funcs, including  df[df['column'].str.contains('|'.join(search))]